# How to set response data to javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to set response data

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    async: true,
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Graphs/get_graphs",
    dataType: 'json',
    data :{hotel_name_realm:$("#hotel_names").val()},
    success : function(res){
       obj = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(obj.upload);
    console.log(obj.download);



series: [{
    name: 'Download',
    data: [
     (obj.Download) // I need set obj.download data here
    ]

}


}
```

[Here is my console.log(obj) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkVVS.png)

Comment: Finally it should be like this      series: [{
        name: 'Download',
        data: [
         (0.1,0.25,0.3,0.24,0.1,)
        ]

    }

Comment: Why do you want to change the response? Server gives you response, in javascript you see it as object. Just change the object to whatever you want.

Comment: this is for highcarts javascript code. If I set data as  obj.download graph is not showing

Answer (score 0):

i do like this,

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "chat/searchuser",
      data: {name: $(this).val(), length: "10"}
      })
      .done(function (data) {
      $('#scroll_user').val('10');
      var html = '';
      $.each(JSON.parse(data).data, function (k, v) {
      html += '<div class="row sideBar-body getUserdata userchat" data-username="' + v.fname + '" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" onclick="showDiv()" id="' + v.fname + '"><div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sideBar-avatar"><div class="avatar-icon"><img src="<?= base_url('assets/user2.jpg') ?>"></div></div><div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sideBar-main"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sideBar-name" data-username="' + v.fname + '"><span class="name-meta">' + v.fname + ' ' + v.lname + '(' + v.username + ')</span></div></div></div></div>'
      $('#usersindiv').html(html);
     });
    }).fail(function () {
     alert("failed");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, you just missed the right square bracket. JS is also case sensitive, obj.Download is not obj.download

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    async: true,
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Graphs/get_graphs",
    dataType: 'json',
    data :{hotel_name_realm:$("#hotel_names").val()},
    success : function(res){
       obj = JSON.parse(res);
       console.log(obj.upload);
       console.log(obj.download);

       series: [{
          name: 'Download',
          data: [
            (obj.Download) // shouldn' it be obj.download? (small D)
          ]
       ] // you are missing the right bracket here
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code that you mentioned. But still not showing my graph

Comment: @ThilinaSameera Then you should show us also the highcharts code. You should change the series in Highcharts object, [look here](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update)